# How do I fill in the rest of an image with a certain color after rotating an ROI with scikit-image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have the following image:

[image]

I am attempting to use handwritten OCR to capture this number,  and for some images, I need to manually rotate the image.

The code I am using to rotate this image is the following:

When I execute this code, the following image is the result:

[image]

I want the white background surrounding the 1 to completely encase the 1. I do not want the upper left and upper right of the image to have the black areas (triangles).

I have tried to adjust the resizing, but this does not seem to help. Does anyone have an idea as to what I can do to prevent this?

Comment: instead of a binary image, make the black have a value different than 0 (eg: white=2, black = 1), so when you rotate you will have 3 regions: the white (3), the black (2), and the new added region that will have a value of 0. then just replace the 0 values for the value of white (3) and binarize again with a threshold of 2.5

Comment: Use the cval argument in the rotate. Set it to 255. See https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.rotate

Comment: you didn't rotate that with any OpenCV function though, you did that with scikit-image.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by fmw42 in the comments, the API you are using has optional arguments to deal with this.

Please peruse the docs for the API you use: [`skimage.transform.rotate`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.rotate)

The docs offer a **`mode`**, which says how to fill in those pixels that don't come from the source image.

[The modes replicate/**edge** and **constant**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html#numpy.pad) should be of interest to you.

- `edge` Pads with the edge values of array.
- `constant` (default) Pads with a constant value, in conjunction with the `cval` argument (default 0, i.e. black).

Comment: I said that already above in my comments (i.e. using cval)

Comment: border modes are a general concept. I found it worth pointing that out. OP appears unaware that this is usually configurable, or a thing that can be wished

Comment: apart from that, my comments have been turned into answers by others plenty of times. this site even encourages it, even if I generally don't appreciate or do that. I think it's time I tried to follow that guideline too.

Comment: It is no problem. I appreciate the expansion. It generally helps the OP. I just wanted to point out that I had already mentioned it.